# Finding the Probability of A

Tags: probability

In a sample space, events $A$ and $B$ are such that $P(A) = P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B) = P(A'\cap B') $. What is $P(A)$?

I came across this question. They pose it like there is only one correct answer is this the case?

Comment: By $A'$ and $B'$ do you mean the compliments?

Comment: Yes I do mean the compliments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $A'\cap B' = (A\cup B)'.$ Thus:
$$P(A\cup B)+ P(A'\cap B') = 1 \Rightarrow P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) + P(A'\cap B') = 1.$$
Since $P(A\cap B) = P(A'\cap B')$ and $P(A) = P(B)$, this becomes:
$$2P(A) = 1 \Rightarrow P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$$